# Date Field Range Fixing in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

In Flex i have two date fields startdate and enddate..
 now, if i select a start date the date range for the end date should show only the next two days..(i.e: End date = start date + 2 days and other days should be disabled and cant be selected).

```
 private function onScroll():void {
            endDate.selectableRange("");}
<mx:DateField id="startDt" change="onScroll()"/>
<mx:DateField id="endDate"/>
```

Need suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this... this could be help you

```
<mx:DateField id="stDate"/>
<mx:DateField id="endDate" selectableRange="{{rangeStart: stDate.selectedDate,rangeEnd:new Date(stDate.selectedDate.fullYear,stDate.selectedDate.month,stDate.selectedDate.date+2)}}"/>
```